# select area within characters using regex (spaces are an issue)

Tags: regex

Some other guy asked a similar question earlier which got a lot of down votes, and I was interested in solving it. I came to a similar issue and would like some help with it.

Take into consideration this wall of text:

```
__don't__ and __do it__

__yellow__

__green__ and __purple__
```

I would like to select all the area within the underscores `__`'s

I attempted the following regex:
`/__[!-~]+__/g` which worked great on most things. I would like to add the ability to have spaces within the underscores. `__do it__` will not be encapsulated in the search because it includes a space which was ruled out by the regex. I attempted the following:

`/__[ -~]+__/g`

It didn't work as planned, and selected everything from the very first `__` to the very last. I was wondering how to tell the regex it has reached the end of a search once it sees a space after a `__`.

Here is the regex you could play around with below:

http://regexr.com/39br7

I tried using `__[^ ]/g` at the end but It didn't seem to help.

Comment: try the regex `/__[ !-~]+?__/g` note the `?` which makes the `+` [lazy/reluctant](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use the below regex,

```
__[^_]*__
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mH2jX4/3)

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the `*`. It states that it `matches 0 or more of the preceding token`

Comment: yes, the preceding token in our case is `[^_]` which mean any character not of `_` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```
__(.*?)__
```

This seems to work.Look at the demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lJ1jB1/1